# MySQL order strings as integers with integers first

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
SELECT code
FROM lock
ORDER BY code * 1
```

This would return the following results:

```
|code| 
|T6  |
|X30 |  
|4   |
```

I need to change the query so it returns the `code` rows in this order:

```
|code|
|4   |
|T6  |
|X30 |
```

The `code` column is of type `VARCHAR`, hence the *hacky* cast in the query. Any ideas?

Comment: So the sorting is always based on numbers in the accessing order and they are always at the end ?

Comment: Would you like to interpret every number in the string, or treat the string as a number only if the whole string is a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM t
ORDER BY 
CAST(code AS signed) > 0 DESC,
code
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0045f/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I know one ugly, but working solution:)

```
ORDER BY
`code` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' DESC,
`code` DESC
```

REGEXP will return 1 on match and 0 when there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM       lock
ORDER BY CASE WHEN code LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END ASC ,
        code
```